# VBA Code to auto-click OK in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have made an Excel macro that gives results using solver. After the result is generated it displays a dialogue box to accept the result. As I have 50 solver results in the macro, I have to click OK 50 times.

Is there some tweak in VBA that can be done to automatically click OK or press enter?

Comment: Why not just take the dialogue box out of the code?  Just put the solver data into a sheet or something.  Why have a box pop up if you just want to automatically clear it?

Comment: The dialogue box is not generated by me in VBA. It is the result display of excel solver that is implemented in the macro. Please help me with sendkeys command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendKeys "~" did the work for me. Type this code after the solversolve command and enter gets automatically typed pressing OK and closing the box.

Answer (score 6):

there is an easier way. 
type this in your code: "solversolve(true)" True makes solver return the results without displaying the Solver Results dialog box

Comment: SendKeys, DisplayAlerts - MSDN says to use `SolverSolve` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197237.aspx ).  Can even execute another macro rather than display the solution form - why wouldn't you use this method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a SendKeys command in vba.  This allows you to simulate keystrokes.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but try `Application.DisplayAlerts`

That is, modify your macro:

```vb
Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'turns off dialog prompts

your_macro_code_here

Application.DisplayAlerts = True     'turns back on dialog prompts for normal usage
```

Comment: While this is an "answer" it is typically good to give reasons why or sources to back up answers instead of "not sure" guesses.